why does my ndk-stack fail to symbolicate a Unity il2cpp crash stack?
our Google Play console is unable to symbolicate our crash stacks. To debug this, I'm trying to symbolicate it locally using ndk-stack but I can't get it to work locally either. Does anyone see anything obviously wrong with our setup?
Our app is an il2cpp Unity 2022.3.21f1 app. We're uploading the following relevant symbols in our aab file (in folder BUNDLE-METADATA/com.android.tools.build.debugsymbols/arm64-v8a):
-rw-r--r--@  1 user.dude  staff     8304 Dec 31  1969 libil2cpp.so.dbg
-rw-r--r--@  1 user.dude  staff     6680 Dec 31  1969 libmain.so.dbg
-rw-r--r--@  1 user.dude  staff     8728 Dec 31  1969 libunity.so.dbg

I am aware that libmain and libunity are supposed to be 'public symbol files' which are supposed to be small, but don't 6.6 and 8.7k seem too small?
I am aware that libil2cpp is supposed to be generated by Gradle, and is supposed to be full debug symbol file. Doesn't 8.3k also seem small?
Here is an example of a crash stack we're trying to symbolicate:
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 16161 >>> com.redacted.m3 <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000dfb0a0  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libunity.so (BuildId: ################)
  #01  pc 0000000000dfb278  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libunity.so (BuildId: ################))
  #02  pc 0000000000dfb3ac  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libunity.so (BuildId: ################))
  #03  pc 000000000068374c  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libunity.so (BuildId: ################))
  #04  pc 0000000001e88d30  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #05  pc 0000000001f01ff8  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #06  pc 0000000001f0be48  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #07  pc 0000000001f0bdd0  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #08  pc 0000000001f0a794  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #09  pc 0000000001ec2d2c  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #10  pc 0000000001ec2d5c  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #11  pc 0000000001e9a374  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #12  pc 0000000001e9a1c0  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #13  pc 0000000001edccec  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #14  pc 00000000042a8af0  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #15  pc 00000000042a048c  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #16  pc 00000000042924ac  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #17  pc 00000000042a1f50  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #18  pc 00000000042a1e14  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #19  pc 0000000004297600  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #20  pc 0000000001e0070c  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #21  pc 0000000001eb583c  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #22  pc 0000000001ede080  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #23  pc 0000000001e9ec58  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #24  pc 0000000001eeab24  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #25  pc 0000000001eb7768  /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #26  pc 0000000000101d5c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+204)
  #27  pc 0000000000095bc0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)

However when I run these through the command
$NDK/ndk-stack -sym /Users/user.dude/Downloads/BUNDLE-METADATA/com.android.tools.build.debugsymbols/arm64-v8a -dump crash.txt

I get this following unhelpful output:
********** Crash dump: **********
#00 0x0000000000dfb0a0 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libunity.so (BuildId: ################)
#01 0x0000000000dfb278 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libunity.so (BuildId: ################)
#02 0x0000000000dfb3ac /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libunity.so (BuildId: ################)
#03 0x000000000068374c /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libunity.so (BuildId: ################)
#04 0x0000000001e88d30 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#05 0x0000000001f01ff8 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#06 0x0000000001f0be48 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#07 0x0000000001f0bdd0 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#08 0x0000000001f0a794 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#09 0x0000000001ec2d2c /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#10 0x0000000001ec2d5c /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#11 0x0000000001e9a374 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#12 0x0000000001e9a1c0 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#13 0x0000000001edccec /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#14 0x00000000042a8af0 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#15 0x00000000042a048c /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#16 0x00000000042924ac /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#17 0x00000000042a1f50 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#18 0x00000000042a1e14 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#19 0x0000000004297600 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#20 0x0000000001e0070c /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#21 0x0000000001eb583c /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#22 0x0000000001ede080 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#23 0x0000000001e9ec58 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#24 0x0000000001eeab24 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#25 0x0000000001eb7768 /data/app/~~REDACTED==/com.redacted.m3-REDACTED-REDACTED-sw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libil2cpp.so (BuildId: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
#26 0x0000000000101d5c /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+204)
#27 0x0000000000095bc0 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)

Does anyone know what I can try next to get this to work?
